# Scala class constructor local parameters

Tags: scala

Can I pass arguments to Scala class constructor that are not stored into class itself?
I want to achieve functionality which in Java could be written as follows:

```java
class A {
    private final SomethingElse y;
    public A(Something x) {
          y = x.derive(this);
    }
}
```

I.e. class constructor takes parameter that is later transformed to another value using reference to `this`. The parameter is forgotten after constructor returns.

In Scala I can do:

```scala
class A(x: Something) {
    val y = x.derive(this)
}
```

But it means that `x` is stored in the class, which I want to avoid. Since `x.derive` method uses reference to `this`, I can not make the transformation in companion object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But it means that x is stored in the class, which I want to avoid.

If you don't reference constructor argument anywhere except the constructor itself, field won't be created. If you reference `x` e.g. in `toString()`, Scala will automatically create and assign private `val` for you.

Use `javap -c -private A` to verify what kind of fields are actually created.

BTW you pass `this` inside a constructor, which means `a.derive()` gets a reference to possibly non-initialized instance of `A`. Be careful!